# conexion entre php y Oracle 11 g express

Tags: php, oracle-11g

Tengo el siguiente codigo para hacer una impresion de los datos de una tabla creada en Oracle, pero al probarlo en mi pagina web me sale el siguiente error y no se cual sea la solucion, ya que es la primera vez que uso oracle como base de datos el conocimiente que tengo sobre la misma es minima

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\xampp1\htdocs\TiendaHomero\datos.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp1\htdocs\TiendaHomero\datos.php on line 4

```
 <?php
    $conexion = oci_connect("PROYECTO", "presariocq43", "localhost/xe"); 
    $consulta = mysqli_query ($conexion,"SELECT * FROM PROYECTO.AUTOMOVIL");
    $nfilas = mysqli_num_rows ($consulta);  

    if ($nfilas > 0)
    {
        print "Nuestros vehiculos"; print "<br>";   print "<br>";
        for ($i=0; $i<$nfilas; $i++)
        {
            $fila = mysqli_fetch_array ($consulta);
            print " Marca: " . $fila["marca"] ;print "<br>";
            print " Modelo: " . $fila["modelo"] ;print "<br>";
            print " Precio: $" . $fila["precio"] ;print "<br>";
            print " Cantidad: " . $fila["cantidad"] ;print "<br>";
            print "<br>";
            print "<br>";

        }
    }

    else{
        print "No se tienen datos";
    }   
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <title> Vehiculos </title>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>loguear</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>SELECCIONES EL CARRO QUE DESEA COMPRAR</h2>


    <form method="POST" action="comprar.php">
    Ford Fiesta<input type="radio" name="marca" required /><br />
    <img src ="4.jpg"width ="250"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Comprar">
    </form>

    <form method="POST" action="comprar2.php">

    Chevrolet Spark GT<input type="radio" name="marca" required /><br />
    <img src ="3.jpg"width ="250"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Comprar">
    </form>

    <form method="POST" action="comprar3.php">

    BMW - S1000RR<input type="radio" name="marca" required /><br />
    <img src ="5.jpg"width ="250"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Comprar">
    </form>


    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="eliminar.php">
    <input type="submit" value="PARA ELIMINAR ALGUN VEHICULO, PRESIONE AQUI"></a><br /></a>
    </form>



     <center>   
     <body style="background-color:white;">

    </form>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes usar `mysqli_query` con una conexión de `oci_connect`, los recursos no son compatibles. Debes usar las funciones de `oci`, no `mysqli`.

Tu código quedaría algo así:

```
<?php
$conexion = oci_connect("PROYECTO", "presariocq43", "localhost/xe"); 
$consulta = oci_parse($conexion, "SELECT * FROM PROYECTO.AUTOMOVIL");
oci_execute($consulta);
$nfilas = oci_num_rows ($consulta);  

if ($nfilas > 0)
{
    print "Nuestros vehiculos"; print "<br>";   print "<br>";
    for ($i=0; $i<$nfilas; $i++)
    {
        $fila = oci_fetch_array ($consulta);
        print " Marca: " . $fila["marca"] ;print "<br>";
        print " Modelo: " . $fila["modelo"] ;print "<br>";
        print " Precio: $" . $fila["precio"] ;print "<br>";
        print " Cantidad: " . $fila["cantidad"] ;print "<br>";
        print "<br>";
        print "<br>";

    }
}

else{
    print "No se tienen datos";
}   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<title> Vehiculos </title>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>loguear</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>SELECCIONES EL CARRO QUE DESEA COMPRAR</h2>


<form method="POST" action="comprar.php">
Ford Fiesta<input type="radio" name="marca" required /><br />
<img src ="4.jpg"width ="250"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Comprar">
</form>

<form method="POST" action="comprar2.php">

Chevrolet Spark GT<input type="radio" name="marca" required /><br />
<img src ="3.jpg"width ="250"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Comprar">
</form>

<form method="POST" action="comprar3.php">

BMW - S1000RR<input type="radio" name="marca" required /><br />
<img src ="5.jpg"width ="250"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Comprar">
</form>


</form>
<form method="POST" action="eliminar.php">
<input type="submit" value="PARA ELIMINAR ALGUN VEHICULO, PRESIONE AQUI"></a><br /></a>
</form>



 <center>   
 <body style="background-color:white;">

</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basicamente si quiero usar una pagina web que funcionaba con mysql ahora me toca cambiar todo a comandos de oracle?

Comment: Si, cada libreria tiene sus propios metodos, en caso de querer moverte de un servidor a otro la opción que puedes para hacer un switch rápido (en nativo); Es hacerte una clase que maneje tus conexiones dependiendo del servidor que quieras usar en ese momento.

Comment: Tengo otro problemita con el codigo, ya deja de mostrar los errores pero aun no imprime lo que hay en la tabla que ya tengo hecha en oracle, estaba pensando si las variables de conexion y consulta estan bien declaradas, ya que como tal tengo un folder principal que se llama PROYECTO y dentro de ese folder estan las tablas, no sabria como declararlas ya que en mysql era mas simple creo

Comment: pruebo en la consola sql de oracle este comando  SELECT * FROM PROYECTO.AUTOMOVIL; e imprime todo lo que necesito, pero si lo aplico al codigo en el php, ya no funciona

Comment: Hace un var_dump($fila); y miras que te trae el oci_fetch

Comment: Cambia el oci_fetch_array por oci_fetch_assoc, con eso se resuelve